# Using execfile to go to a directory then run a variable

Tags: python, execfile

I am making a Python text-assistant. I am trying to use execfile() to run the questions. The file used to ask the question and the command files are in different directories so I cant use import (filename).

My question is how can i run multiple parts, including a variable, in my execfile

This is what I have:
    execfile ('C:/hidden/assistant/AnsData/', variable, '.py')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where the file to import is, you don't have to resort to `execfile` hackery. At worst, you can do:

```
import importlib
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/hidden/assistant/AnsData/')
# "variable" is a string naming your module without the .py extension
answermodule = importlib.import_module(variable)
```

Comment: how would i make it run with the .py extension?

Comment: The import machinery assumes it will already have a `.py` extension. If that's not what you're asking, please clarify.